Bobby Fischer and "the genetic guy" in Iceland - sources?
I recall Bobby Fischer being quoted as saying "I worked harder" as the explanation for his supremacy at chess, rather than inherited genes. I thought that this was in Garðar Sverrisson's book Bobby Fischer: The Final Years, but it wasn't. Sverrisson describes a mutual antipathy between Fischer and the director of an international biotechnology company who seemed to think he was some kind of "natural phenomenon", but he doesn't give the quote I remember.
Has more been written about this director whom Fischer called "the genetic guy" and his interest in Fischer? Sverrison says he appeared in a documentary about Fischer, one that was "spiced up" with "creative medical diagnoses". Which one? What's his name?
